# Iterating over key value pairs and adding values, data cleanse Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

I'm working with python to extract data from a csv statement. I want to cleanse the data and  transfer this to another spreadsheet. So to explain names like esso and bp become get categorised under "fuel" and added together. Importantly I want to find the sum of these and transfer it. So far I have created the dictionary etc and have played with iterating over it my challenge is getting the values.

```
df = pd.read_csv("statement.csv")
item = df['Transaction Description']
cost = df['Debit Amount']

purchases = {}

purchases = {}
for key, value in zip(item, cost):
purchases[key] = value
```

So my initial aim was for something like defining rent, fuel etc as variables and then:

```
for i in key {
    if i = Sanctuary housing rent.value = value
    else
        i = RSS CHANTRY FIELDS etc.....
}
```

However I've since discovered comprehensions. But the solutions offered/described seem to be more about multiple items rather than pulling data from particular keys. I have also heard this is a computationally expensive method? Therefore I'm now toying with the idea of using something similar to:

```
a_key = "c"

values_of_key = [a_dict[a_key]
```

from https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-find-the-values-of-a-key-in-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-python# I guess this could be an easier method?

```
df = pd.read_csv("statement.csv")
```

item = df['Transaction Description']

cost = df['Debit Amount']
credit =df['Credit amount']

purchases = {}

```
purchases = {}
for key, value in zip(item, cost):
purchases[key] = value

Water = [purchases ['BRISTOLWESSEXWATER']

print(Water)
```

my question is this: is this a good pythonic method? my sticking point is still for multiple values that I want to add. are there any other methods you would recommend? Ideally I want the code to execute quite quickly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The process of translating a transaction description to a set of categories could be quite complicated.
I suggest creating a function for that, so that you can modify the logic in there.

Your code could look like this:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

def description_to_category(s):
    # here you have to do a lot of testing and fine-tunning,
    # because this classification process can be quite complicated
    if 'esso' in s or 'bp' in s:
        return 'fuel'

    return 'other'

df = pd.read_csv("statement.csv")
col_description = df['Transaction Description']
col_cost = df['Debit Amount']

purchases_by_category = collections.defaultdict(0)
for description, cost in zip(col_description, col_cost):
    category = description_to_category(description)

    # add cost; defaultdict will have 0 for new keys
    purchases_by_category[category] += cost

print(purchases_by_category)
```

Comment: Thanks Ralf, i was just looking at the python docs and toying with the idea of accessing keys and comparing words to a predefined list. but im not sure how i can just start grabbing values and adding them.. i also guess this could be slow? ill have a play thanks really appreciated